# How to generate QR CODE for dynamic generating link and logo using Simple QrCode in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-8, qr-code

I want to generate 'Image inside QR CODE' with dynamic url and Image. I have mentioned the below error and code. Used the https://www.simplesoftware.io/#/docs/simple-qrcode laravel framework to generate QR Cocde

```
 
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->merge({{ url('/') }}/{{ $card_details->profile}}, .2, true)->size(200)->generate({{ url('/') }}/{{ $card_details->card_url }})) !!} ">
```

If I give image with direct link and url, It works proper But I wanted to make it dynamic.

**Error**

```
production.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected '<'
```

Comment: any solution  for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already use tag `{!!` and you don't need to use `{{` it anymore

````
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->size(100)->generate(url('/qr_code/invoice?no_inv=' . $detail->waybill->encrypt_data)),
) !!}" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">```
````